# MS Access: Go to a record on a form from a combo/list box

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I would like to be able to open a record (find record) on my form from a list box and combo box I have on the left side of my form. I want to use them as a means a navigation.

Ive Included a picture: [My Form and navigation set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZASnL.png)

Answer (score 0):

First off, write a function that fetches the data that you want to populate into the fields on the right. Have it take the ID as a parameter, like:

```
public function FillWithData(recordId as int)
dim s as string
dim r as new adodb.recordset
s = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE IdField =" & recordId & ";"
r.Open s, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, dbSQLPassThrough
Exit Function    
End Function
```

Secondly, add an On Click event to the list.

```
Private Sub myList_Click()
dim id as int
id = myList.Column(1) 'the number here is the index of the column that contains the record id in the RowSource of the List.
Call FillWithData(id)
Exit Sub
End Sub
```